# Convert table items into single list

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, list

What should be the best approach in Excel to get records like these:

[image]

consolidated into a table like this:

[image]

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This a multi step solution. IT uses the name manager that is on the formula tab of the ribbon.  I placed the two ranges starting at A1, & A7.  Adjust as needed for where the actual are located. 
[image]

Step 1, extract the values for each color. For this I used an offset command.
For red  it is Offset($a$1,1 meaning one row underneath the name cell. Green will be 2, and blue will be 3.

the next part of the offset is how many columns over. for location, I extracted the location number by using 0+right($a8,1). For Spec, I used 3+right(a$7).

to convert it to a color, I checked if both the location and the spec was a 1, else it was a blank.

to place the commas, I checked if both Red & Green for comma1, and for comma2, Blue plus red or green

Entry just added the colors and the commas. place =entry in the cells in the second table

The full set of name is

BL      =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,3,0+RIGHT(Sheet1!$A3,1))

BS  =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,3,3+RIGHT(Sheet1!D$7,1))

Blue    =IF(BL+BS=2,"Blue","")

Comma1  =IF(LEN(Red&Green)>5, ", ","")

Comma2  =IF(Blue="","",IF(Red=Green,"", ", "))

Entry   =Red & Comma1 & Green & Comma2 & Blue

GL  =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,2,0+RIGHT(Sheet1!$A9,1))

Green   =IF(GL+GS=2,"Green","")

GS  =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,2,3+RIGHT(Sheet1!D$7,1))

Red =IF(RL+RS=2,"Red","")

RL  =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,1,0+RIGHT(Sheet1!$A13,1))

RS  =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,1,3+RIGHT(Sheet1!D$7,1))